# How to copy a polygon in eagle from one layer to multiple others in library (package) editor?

Tags: eaglecad, library, eda

I have to layout kind of several boiler plates for layouts. I thought of designing it as a package in the library editor.

Some drawing elements have to be present on any layer and some other have to be present on several different layers.

I could copy them to one layer after another, but this is tedious, error prone and tedious to check.

I tried to use copy wire-to-any-layer.ulp but it doesn't work in the library editor. Any hints? I'm using the latest version (7.7.0 Ultimate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are really asking about, but it seems you have a polygon in one layer, and you want to copy it to another layer.  At least that's what I'll answer.

As far as I know, there is no direct way to copy to another layer.  However, this can be done in a few relatively simple steps:

Copy the polygon to some unused space in the same layer.

Group the copy

In the command line textbox, issue the command CHANGE LAYER [layer number]

Right click beside the group you created from the copy and accept "change group"

click on the MOVE arrowhead icon

right click near the group you created and issue the command "move group"

Do a MOVE on the group to position the copy, now in the new layer, to where to want it.

Comment: This is the way I did it until now, with some minor variations. But I'd prefer an easy way to have the polygon, let's say a company logo, on every layer in a single step (i.e. by using an ulp or script)

Comment: @Ariser: Tell marketing to live with the logo only in the silkscreen layer.

Comment: :-) If it were only the marketing fools I had to circumvent. I have to evade legal and internal process dept. too.

Comment: @Ariser Put it on `20 Dimension` layer. This layer is plotted in all output files.

Comment: @Jero: No, that's a bad idea.  The dimension layer has other purposes, and putting a logo there conflicts with those purposes.  It not only tells Eagle where the edges of the board are, but directions for milling and sometimes drilling the board are derived from it.  You could a separate layer, but then having copper derived from multiple layers when plotting is dangerous as there can easily be shorts that you and the DRC don't see.  Again, really bad idea.

Comment: @Jero, I know. PCB fab will warn you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that my answer is similar to that of @Olin, but looks like quicker and simpler. It covers the case, when you want to copy a polygon to another layer, but have it exactly in the same spot (like when beefing-up a heatsink plane and needing it for example on both top layer and bottom layer).
Of course, you can move it to another spot afterwards if you wish.

In short: Select / Copy & Paste / Move via Property editing

In detail:

```
1. Select the desired polygon (gets highlighted)
2. Click on the Copy icon
3. Click on the selected polygon TWICE (basically you did Copy and Paste)
   (at this point there are two equal polygons on the same layer and same place)
4. Right click on the selected polygon (menu will pop-up)
5. Select the Properties line from the popup menu
6. Modify the Layer property to where you want to move it
```